# Three-way Eloquent relashionships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have three tables that are related, though they don't seem to fit any example from the documentation or I'm not realizing which one.

Here's an example of the tables:

`Devices` table:

```
| id |    Name   |
|----|:---------:|
| 1  |   Samsung |
| 2  |   Second  |
| 3  | Some Name |
```

`Categories` table:

```
| id |       Name      |
|----|:---------------:|
| 1  |  Some Category  |
| 2  |  Camera         |
| 3  |  Other Category |
```

`Specs` table:

```
| id |    Value   | category_id | device_id |
|----|:----------:|-------------|-----------|
| 1  | Some specs | 2           | 1         |
| 2  |    13MP    | 2           | 1         |
| 3  | Last specs | 1           | 2         |
```

Now let's say I want to run a query like "select from devices where camera=13MP". 
To be more explicit, I want to be able to use `where('Camera', '13MP')` instead of `where('2', '13MP')`.

I already have the basic relationships setup ( `Device` has many `Specs`, `Category` has many `Specs`, `Specs` belongs to `Device` and `Category`).

I don't see how I could make the relationships or if Eloquent is able to do this with a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a ManyToMany relationship in your `Devices` class:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Category::class)->withPivot('Value');
}
```

Setup a ManyToMany relationship in your `Category` Class:

```
public function devices(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Device::class)->withPivot('Value');
}
```

Then if you want to get devices that have cameras of 13MP then you can do this:

```
$devices = Category::where('Name', 'Camera')->first()->devices()->wherePivot('Value', '13MP')->get();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm getting the following error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `Name` = Camera and `pivot` = value limit 1)`.

Comment: I had a mistake in my answer I have adjusted it. Try again. `$devices = Category::where('Name', 'Camera')->first()->devices()->wherePivot('Value', '13MP')->get();`